# How to populate dropdownlist dynamically in mvc3 from two tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have created mvc3 application.
where using EF to populate dropdownlist from tables.

now I have `two dropdownlists` on my `index.cshtml` each populating from different tables.

code index.cshtml:

i have taken model as entity as it is having both my tables `table1` and `table2`

`@model Mapping.Models.mydataEntities1`

but problem is here i'm not able to select values from both tables. :(

like following code is for only working when i give 
model `@model Mapping.Models.table1`

but need to select values into two dropdown from different tables

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.CategoryId, 
        new SelectList(Model.Categories, "Value", "Text"),
        "-- Select category --"
    )
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

How can i do this?

I have used EF

```
 public partial class mydataEntities1 : DbContext
    {
        public mydataEntities1()
            : base("name=mydataEntities1")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public DbSet<table1> table1 { get; set; }
        public DbSet<table2> table2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your model `mydataEntities1`. If it has both your tables populated correctly, it should works

Comment: Use the ViewModel @Iron Ninja shows and read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx - see also http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc If there is anything missing let me know and I'll add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an EF user, but assuming that your model is populated and works correctly 
the following code should works

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.table1.CategoryId, 
    new SelectList(Model.table1.Categories, "Value", "Text"),
    "-- Select category --"
)

@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.table2.CategoryId, 
    new SelectList(Model.table2.Categories, "Value", "Text"),
    "-- Select category --"
)
```

But I strongly reccomend you to create a ViewModel to expose your data to the View and not your domain entities or directly the repository.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend having an actual 'Model' instead of just pushing the data entities directly into the views. Something like this may be what you should use for your model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Mapping.Models.table1 table1;
    public Mapping.Models.table2 table2;
}
```

and then your model would become

```
@model MyModel
```

Answer (score 0):

view code

```
   <%: Html.DropDownList("courses","--select--")%>
```

controller code

public ActionResult Index()
        {  newclass nw = new newclass();

```
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> lt = nw.method().Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = c.EmpName,
            Value = c.EmpId.ToString()
        });
        ViewData["courses"] = lt;

        return View();
    }
```

model code

public class newclass
    {
        DataClasses2DataContext db = new DataClasses2DataContext();
        public IEnumerable method()
        {
            List lt = (from val in db.Employees select new Class1 { EmpName = val.EmpName, EmpId = val.EmpId }).Distinct().ToList();
            if (lt != null)
            {
                var values = from val in lt orderby val.EmpId select val;
                return values;
            }
            else
                return null;
        }

```
}
public class Class1
{

    public int EmpId{get;set;}
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string location { get; set; }
    public Int64 Phno{get;set;}

}
```

add model class namespace to controller and try it  hope this will work perfectly to fill dropdownlist in asp.net mvc3